# central coordinates of regular map tiles

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to retrieve a set of static map tiles from Google Maps using the simple web services API.

For zoom level 0, where there is only one tile, I simply specify the center as (0,0), which is trivial. (And yes, I am aware, that the south-north range is [-85.05113°,85.05113°] *only*, i. e. I have read about [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) (not only the Wikipedia article).

So for zoom level 1 with 2×2 tiles I know that it'd be naive to think the central coordinates of the tiles would be (±90,±45). I applied one of the functions listed in above article's "[Derivation of the Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Derivation_of_the_Mercator_projection)" section. In PHP this looks like

```
function mercor($aLat) {
  return rad2deg(asinh(tan(deg2rad($aLat))));
}
```

which always returns 50.498987 when passing in 45. I tried several of the alternative expressions :-) all with the same result, indeed, and even checked that value with a dedicated calculator.

Anyway, the value is obviously not correct, as you can see here (which *was* supposed to show the north west quadrant of the Earth's map, but here the equator is *shifted* to the north) ([image source](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=50.498987,-90&zoom=1&size=256x256&sensor=false)):

[image]

By trial and error I found the correct value to be close to 66.65, but I have no idea how to calculate that. I tried several manipulations of the `R` factor shown in the expressions in that mentioned "Derivation of the Mercator projection" section, and also fiddled with the "Scale factor" described in the same document, but whatever I do, I do not come close to 66.65.

Here you can see that 66.65 is the (close to) correct value, the equator at the bottom edge ([image source](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=66.65,-90&zoom=1&size=256x256&sensor=false)):

[image]

And taking an illustration like, for example ([image source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Mercator-proj.png)):

[image]

and a tool like kruler, it also becomes obvious that it should be 66.65.

So, any idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

(Currently I'm trying it from withing HTML documents, because it's relatively simple, but later I'd like to do it from an environment in which I have no way to call JavaScript. so the JavaScript API is not an option.)

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a website describing the popular tiling system used behind Google Maps, OSM and similar slippy maps. Have a look at:

http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

With a click on the interactive map you receive bounds calculated in both the Mercator coordinates (in meters) as well as WGS84 lat/lon (in geodetic degrees).

Down on the page you find an open-source python code (which has been in the meanwhile ported to other programming languages by other people). This contains documented description of all the math you may need.

In fact, I have created this resource after working for Google SoC on the GDAL2Tiles/MapTiler project - which has been reimplemented into C/C++ and significantly improved and is now available via http://www.maptiler.com/.

UPDATE:
If you want to use the Google Maps Static API requests you may find useful another online tool which I prepared: http://www.maptiler.org/photoshop-google-maps-overlay-tiles/.
Feel free to review the JavaScript source code.